# Did the Roman Republic really have 60 legions?

Tags: military, ancient-rome

A common claim is that during the last civil war of the republic, the combined legions of Antony and Octavian totaled 60 legions. Another variant is that Octavian alone commanded 60 legions after defeating Antony. For example, [here](https://www.pbs.org/empires/romans/empire/soldiers.html).

This is an enormous number of soldiers, but I can't find any source, and numbers are very contradictory. Is this number from some ancient source or some list of legions? Is it accurate?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Size_of_the_Roman_army)  [Wikipedia 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Roman_legions) [WIkipedia 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_army_of_the_mid-Republic),  [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-many-legions-did-Rome-have-in-the-field-at-its-peak-power); [Encyclopedia](https://www.worldhistory.org/Roman_Army/) [RomanRepublic](https://imperiumromanum.pl/en/roman-army/units-of-roman-army/roman-legion/)most of these have sources - do they help? if not, why not?  Most of these claim 28 legions, 60 centuries.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Size_of_the_Roman_army) contains the same claim, and also demonstrates that it is problematic: "*At the end of civil war between Mark Antony and Octavian there were around 60 legions, although few were at full strength.[citation needed]*"

Comment: A good place to start is Wikipedia's [War of Actium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_of_Actium) as this was the last civil war of the republic.

Comment: The same claim in Lesley Adkins and Roy A. Adkins, "Handbook of Life in Ancient Rome, Updated Edition", New York: Facts on File 2004, p. 56: *"Various legions were formed, captured, reconstituted and destroyed up to the battle of Actium in 31 BC. Since each commander that formed legions used his own numbering system (generally beginning with I), the situation is very confused, and duplicate numbers are common. Very often little is known about a legion other than that it had fought for a particular commander. There were about 60 legions by the end of the civil war."*

Comment: @njuffa Do you know whether that particular claim has a source?

Comment: From a [book review](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4389363) of H.M.D. Parker, "The Roman Legions", Oxford: Clarendon Press 1928: *"The Battle of Actium put an end to the Civil Wars. Augustus (Octavian), now the sole master of the Roman world, had on his hands an immense army of about 60 legions [...]"*

Comment: Possible clue in Martin Goodman, "The Roman World 44 BC - AD 180, 2nd ed.", Routledge 2012: "Thus when in 30 BC Octavian celebrate his victory over Egypt, it would normally have been expected that he would disband all of the 60 legions under his command. [...] And Octavian did indeed dismiss over half of the legions at tremendous expense, as he proudly recorded in his *Res Gestae* 3.3. But in 25 BC there were still 28 legions and a huge number of auxiliary troops under his command."

Comment: *Res Gestae Divi Augusti* 3.3: "*Millia civium Romanorum adacta sacramento meo fuerunt circiter quingenta. Ex quibus deduxi in colonias aut remisi in municipia sua 
stipendis emeritis millia aliquanto plura quam trecenta et iis omnibus agros adsignavi​ aut pecuniam pro praemis militiae​ dedi.*" So Octavian claims to have had about 500,000 Roman citizens under his command, of which he dismissed and settled / repatriated 300,000. How one gets from those numbers to 60 legions, I do not know, as the strength of a legion is commonly given as 5,000 to 6,000 men.

Comment: I do not know whether the Res Gestae refers to his entire reign, or only to the aftermath of the War of Actium. 500,000 Roman citizens would imply 100 or so legions, which would give a million total soldiers with auxiliaries, which is an enormous number.

Comment: @Master: As can be seen from the linked articles, the number of auxiliaries was about one and a half times the number of legionaries; furthermore, some (reinforced) units (whether legions or centuries) were greater than others, also by a factor of about one a half.

Comment: This was in the late empire. In the early empire, they were about equal.

Comment: @Master: Read the [first three paragraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Size_of_the_Roman_army#Imperial_period).

Comment: First paragraph: "In the time of Tiberius, according to a recent study by Le Bohec, the legionary forces may have reached the considerable figure of 125,000 men, divided into 25 legions, and with additional auxiliary forces for a total of 250,000 soldiers (including around 30,000 cavalry). In addition to this there were 10,000 soldiers garrisoned in the capital, including the Praetorian guard, the urban cohorts, vigiles, equites singulares Augusti and 40,000 marines in the navy"

Comment: 125,000 legionnaires; 125,000 auxiliaries.

Comment: @Master: No. 125,000 legionaries, and 250,000 auxiliaries; the latter do not include the former, as can be seen by comparing the phrasing of first paragraph, with that of the other two.

Comment: The second paragraph says: "Under Trajan the number of legions was brought to 30 (around 165,000 legionaries), while the number of auxiliaries was increased to 380 units (for a total of around 200,000–220,000 men, including 70,000 cavalry), totalling 360,000–380,000 soldiers." This is because, in the middle empire, during Trajan's reign, there were one and a half times as many auxiliaries as there were legionnaires. 165,000 legionnaires and 220,000 auxiliaries. In the early empire, they were equal. This is why it says a "total" of 250,000 soldiers. The army grew from 250,000 to 380,000.

Comment: @Master: Don't you think it's a bit of a coincidence that 125 + 250 = 375 ? Similarly, 165 + 200/220 = 365/385. Likewise, 154 + 223 = 377.

Comment: You're theory would mean the auxiliaries were originally twice the size of the legions, and later decreased in size, something which no source ever says.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132834/discussion-between-lucian-and-master).

Comment: Reading through the WP page on the war, it looks like Antony may have had as many as 23 legions. There's no direct measure of the number Octavian had, but one report said when he allowed retirements, he lost manpower equivalent to 10 legions. So it must have been rather a lot, and 27 doesn't seem outside the realm of reasonableness.

Comment: 60 legions at full strength with 5,000 or 6,000 men each would total about 300,000 to 360,000 men plus auxillaries minus various losses.  In total a few hundred thousand men, possibly as many or as few men as someone believes probable.

Comment: @MAGolding: Your comment is pure gold ! :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR Possibly, but we cannot be sure.**

H. M. D. Parker, "The Roman Legions", Oxford: Clarendon Press 1928, pp. 70-71 goes into some detail, but also points out that an exact accounting is made difficult by the fact that one has to rely on secondary sources.

> The final period of the Republic, from 44 B.C. till the battle of Actium, illustrates the same principles of legionary recruiting. Each side raised the troops necessary for its own purposes, and probably had its own system of notation. The secondary sources from which this period is known do not permit of such a detailed investigation into the numbers of the legions employed as the 'Commentarii' of Caesar. To illustrate the extensive conscription it will, however, be sufficient to cite the figures given for the opposing armies at Philippi and Actium. Brutus and Cassius had nineteen, <sup>1</sup> while their opponents *possessed* more than forty legions.<sup>2</sup> At Actium Antony had thirty-one legions, nineteen forming the land army, <sup>3</sup> eight serving on the fleet, and four stationed in Egypt; <sup>4</sup> Octavian had between forty and forty-five.<sup>5</sup> This represents the highest pitch of a system of conscription dictated by the necessities of a civil war. After the battle Octavian was left with an army numbering upwards of sixty legions.
> <sup>1</sup> Vell. ii. 65.  <sup>2</sup> Livy, Ep. cxxii.  <sup>3</sup> Plut. Ant. 68.  <sup>4</sup> Orosius, vi. 19.  <sup>5</sup> App. B. C. v. 127.

Checking into the cited sources, I am only able to partially confirm the number of legions given by Parker. In the English translation of [Velleius reproduced on LacusCurtius](https://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/e/roman/texts/velleius_paterculus/2c*.html), I find:

> 65 [...] Antony threatened to join forces with Brutus and Cassius, who had now control of seventeen legions, if Caesar rejected this friendly gesture, and said that Caesar was under greater obligations to avenge a father than he to avenge a friend.

This states seventeen legions, not the nineteen referred to by Parker. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ab_Urbe_Condita_Libri), book 122 of Livius' Epitome (*History of Rome*), while covering the relevant time period, 43 BC, is no longer extant, so possibly cited indirectly via some other source.

The English translation of Plutarch's *Life of Antony* found [online at LacusCurtius](https://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/e/roman/texts/plutarch/lives/antony*.html) does mention the nineteen legions of the land army:

> 68 [...] Only a few were aware that Antony had fled, and to those who heard of it the story was at first an incredible one, that he had gone off and left nineteen legions of undefeated men-at‑arms and twelve thousand horsemen, as if he had not many times experienced both kinds of fortune and were not exercised by the reverses of countless wars and fightings.

From the English translation of Orosius found [online at Attalus](http://www.attalus.org/translate/orosius6B.html), it appears that there were eight legions serving on board *Caesar*'s fleet, not Antony's:

> 19 [...] On the third day after the battle, Antony transferred his camp to Actium and prepared to decide the issue by a naval engagement. There were two hundred and thirty beaked ships in Caesar's fleet and thirty without beaks, triremes equal in swiftness to Liburnian vessels; eight legions, not counting five praetorian cohorts, were stationed on board the fleet. Antony's fleet had one hundred and seventy ships, but this smaller number was offset by their exceptional size, for in height they stood ten feet above the level of the sea.

The English translation of the *Civil Wars* section of Appian's *Roman History* at [LacusCurtius](https://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/e/roman/texts/appian/civil_wars/5*.html) does mention forty-five legions at the cited location in book five:

> 127 Octavian neither pursued Pompeius nor allowed others to do so; either because he refrained from encroaching on Antony's dominions, or because he preferred to wait and see what Antony would do to Pompeius and make that a pretext for a quarrel if he should do wrong (for they had long entertained the suspicion that ambition would bring them into mutual conflict when other rivals were out of the way), or, as Octavian said later, because Pompeius was not one of his father's murderers. He now brought his forces together, and they amounted to forty-five legions of infantry, 25,000 horse and some 40,000 light-armed troops, with 600 war-ships; he had also an immense number of merchant-vessels, which nevertheless he sent back to their owners.

In any event, while the exact number of legions at the end of the Roman Republic may not be known exactly, and may in fact be unknowable unless additional sources from antiquity are found, Octavian's own accounting does indicate that after emerging victorious from the Battle of Actium, he was in command of a massive army that may well have comprised the sixty legions mentioned in various history books. [*Res Gestae Divi Augusti* 3.3](https://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/augustus/Res_Gestae/1*.html) states:

> Millia civium Romanorum adacta sacramento meo fuerunt circiter quingenta. Ex quibus deduxi in colonias aut remisi in municipia sua stipendis emeritis millia aliquanto plura quam trecenta et iis omnibus agros adsignavi​ aut pecuniam pro praemis militiae​ dedi.

Octavian claims to have had about 500,000 Roman citizens under his command, of which he dismissed and settled or repatriated 300,000.